# finding current location in android through GPS

Tags: android, gps

Is there possible to get accurate latitude and longitude of a user  through "GPS" after changing its location of very shorter distance like 3-4 feet.

Actually I have made an application in android which gives me latitude and longitude of a user but, it changes its value on a same point or location of a user.

Kindly help me out of this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: See [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Experience says It depends on Phone/Device you are using, if your device support AGPS then getting GPS coordinates will be easier and fast (No related to your coding skill as you will be using android SDK). Normal GPS also return accurate data, try downloading Savaari application from google play, It works like charm, your 2nd Question Yes it is possible to get coordinates after a specific time or distance interval, when ever you are registering your listner you have to provide time and distance (in Meters) after which you want to receive GPS Value.

Check out this snippet : -

```
public void startReadingGPS(int readAfterMinimumTime, int readAfterMinimumDistance ){
        locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, readAfterMinimumTime, readAfterMinimumDistance, this);
    }
```

public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener) 
Added in API level 1
Register for location updates using the named provider, and a pending intent.

See requestLocationUpdates(long, float, Criteria, PendingIntent) for more detail on how to use this method.

Parameters
provider  the name of the provider with which to register 
minTime  minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds 
minDistance  minimum distance between location updates, in meters 
listener  a LocationListener whose onLocationChanged(Location) method will be called for each location update

Comment: Appreciate  your answer, but my another problem is that, I will never change by location but GPS will constantly CHANGES latitude and longitude. please suggest how to stable it in a same location.

Comment: add 8 to 10 meter change in your location listener actually in case of Android GPS its accuracy is about 8 meters which means even if you keep your phone at one place it will keep changing the coordinates my take would be add GPS reading after 10 meters , all the best !

Answer (score 0):

you should implement locationlistener in your activity

```
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

        // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds


        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute


            boolean isGPSEnabled = false; 

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) yourapplicationcontext
                                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                                // getting GPS status
                                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
           if (isGPSEnabled) {
                            if (location == null) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                                if (locationManager != null) {
                                    location = locationManager
                                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                    if (location != null) {
                                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
//Add this permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```